# Adding a JavaScript alert on the input type file prevents the open file dialog from appearing in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, html, input-type-file

I have an input type, ="file". When I try to put `onclick = "alert('test')";`, it shows in both Internet Explorer and Firefox, but in Internet Explorer after I press the OK button, the message will disappear and nothing happens, in Firefox: after the message disappears, the open file dialog appears as normal. How can I show the open file dialog in Internet Explorer after the JavaScript message disappears?

As for Internet Explorer, I am using [Internet Explorer 9](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_9).

Comment: Can you add in the source code so we can see exactly what you're doing?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a return value to the line...

```
onclick="alert('test');return true;"
```

Comment: I've just put the following into an static html file and it is working as expected on my IE9, FF7 and Chrome14 `<html><body><input type="file" onclick="alert('test');" /></body></html>`  Not sure if there are particular settings (maybe security or advanced) in your version of IE9 that are affected your results

Comment: If you want to try the above yourself, [click here](http://www.stonefish.co.uk/test.htm)

Comment: oh i meant that i won't work if you double click on the address field of the input type file, not the browse button itself ... clicking on the browse button will make it to work correctly.

Comment: That would have been useful information from the start.  You might want to update your question so other people don't waste time.  Sorry, I don't have an answer for your revised requirements